# How to convert the int to letters for num Systems in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class StringSplit {

public void execute(){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Programm zur Umrechnung von Zahlensystem (Basen von 2-16)");
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die gewschte Base an:");
    int base = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    System.out.println("jetzt nur noch eine positive Zahl angeben die Sie konvertieren möchten");
    int ziffer = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    System.err.println(ziffer);
    int [] baseArray = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    for(int i = 0;i<baseArray.length;i++)
    {
        if (baseArray[i] == base)
        {
            System.out.println(ziffer +" umgeandelt zur Basis " + baseArray[i] + " = " + convert(ziffer, baseArray[i]));
        }
    }
}

public String convert (int num, int base){
    String convertedNumber = "";
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder (convertedNumber);

    while(num != 0)
    {
        b.append(String.valueOf(num%base));
        num/=base;
    }

    return b.reverse().toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringSplit prg = new StringSplit();
    prg.execute();
}
```

}

I want to create an Array to slove that Problem so if Base is >9 the Compiler should use for 10=A 11=B and so on.
So I m thinking about to use that

```
Char [] decArray={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
```

My problem now is how to check in convert method all bases that use letters ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to handle bases that use letters any differently from those that do not.   Add your `decArray` (declared `char[]`, not Char[]...) and use

```
b.append(decArray[num%base]);
```

in place of

```
b.append(String.valueOf(num%base));
```

EDIT:

If you'd rather use a String constant to provide your digit characters,
you could do something like this:

```
// in StringSplit class, outside any method:
private static final String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";

// inside method convert(int num, int base) :
    b.append(digits.charAt(num % base));
```

Comment: Thanks ! :).   If I would to ve to write it in a string constant how I ve to handle that I never wrote a string constant I searches for it but yea how I ve to use it with that...